Cannot register additional Servlet in Vaadin 24 Spring Boot App
I'm trying to follow this guide: Dynamic content, add an additional Servlet to manage dynamic content, but when I try to visit the associated url vaadin tells me there is no path registered. I'm using Vaadin 24 with spring boot 3.2.2. I tried add @ServletComponentScan but without results.

With Spring, you should probably use a Spring-native way of serving the content instead of creating explicit Servlets.

Just tried the same Dynamic content guide in Vaadin 24.3.10 to no avail.
Couldn't access the servlet URL until I added the mentioned tag @ServletComponentScan tag above the Application class definition:
Application.java    
...
@ServletComponentScan
public class Application implements AppShellConfigurator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
...

Now it works like in Vaadin 8.
